# Google Analytics specific URL for any tracking code

Tags: google-analytics

As I understood, using Google Analytics, I can create a tracking code that I can embed into any application of website. However, is it receive a specific URL that is used for tracking the whole application in order for me to whitelist the traffic with my ISP so that I can charge the traffic for FREE for that specific URL - rather than whitelist the traffic of all google analytics (Which the ISP cannot do due to the heavy traffic generated by it) ?

Comment: Can you try again I don't understand your question.   Adding Google Analytics tracking code to your web site is HTTP Gets or http posts and should not create any traffic to your website.  Its traffic away from it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to whitelist any traffic from your ISP. GA tracking works by collecting data from visitors to your site and has nothing to do with all other traffic on sites hosted by your ISP. As long as you have your tracking code on all of your own pages, then your site traffic will be tracked.